# Error with find and ls

Tags: find, ls

I'm trying to use find and ls to sort files based on date, however, it's not doing anything. Here's my command:

```
find ./.BUBackups -name "test*" -exec ls -t {} \;
```

I also tried:

```
find ./.BUBackups -name "test*" -exec ls -lt {} \;
```

In testing, -t is simply doing -nothing-. -l works, but if I input -t it acts as if I didn't put it in at all. However, *ls -t or ls -lt works perfectly fine when I'm not running it through exec, in others words simply typing ls -t works*

Is this a glitch? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-exec` argument to find executes the specified command once for each file that find locates. So if you have files test_a, test_b, and test_c, your command will be equivalent to:

```
ls -lt test_a
ls -lt test_b
ls -lt test_c
```

In other words, each listing is performed independently per file, so the files will be listed in whatever order find locates them, rather than in order of modification time, like the `-t` option to ls specifies.

What you really want is something like `find ./.BUBackups -name 'test*' | xargs ls -lt`, which, with the example files I used above, would be equivalent to `ls -lt test_a test_b test_c`. Since you're now using one invocation of ls to list all of the files you're interested in, it can put them in the proper mtime order.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks (to both of you)

Answer (score 3):

The reason `-t` isn't working is that `find` is executing `ls` once for each found file separately so the output is in the order the files are found. To make it work the way you expect:

```
find ./.BUBackups -name "test*" -exec ls -lt {} +
```

or

```
find ./.BUBackups -name "test*" -print0 | xargs -0 -exec ls -lt
```

Comment: Does `ls` is guaranteed to be called just one time? Otherwise I guess you'll get multiple lists of sorted files.

Comment: @cYrus: No, not guaranteed. It will be limited to the maximum argument length supported by your system. If you're using `ls -lt` with that many files, you should probably be using a different approach altogether.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks (to both of you)